# How to split a string in postgresql and return another string if empty

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, case

I have one column that I need to split into two based on what is before and after a ':'. If there isn't a ':', I need the second column to read 'None'.

Example:

original_a: Sleepy in America: Why We Are Tired And What To Do About It
headline: Sleepy in America
subtitle: Why We Are Tired And What To Do About It

original_b: Meditation vs Talking Therapy
headline: Meditation vs Talking Therapy
subtitle: 'None'

I tried a subquery

```
SELECT headline, 
       CASE WHEN subtitle = ' ' THEN 'None' ELSE subtitle END as subtitle
FROM ( 
     SELECT split_part(headline, ':', 1) as headline, split_part(headline, ':', 2) as subtitle
     FROM table) as subquery
```

This splits the original column just fine but won't return 'None' when there isn't a second part.

How do I return 'None'? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple [COALESCE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-coalesce/) with a [NULLIF](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-nullif/) which includes empty results?

`COALESCE` returns the first non-null value in its parameters.

`NULLIF` will return NULL if the two arguments match.

```
SELECT 
 SPLIT_PART(headline, ':', 1) AS headline
,COALESCE(NULLIF(SPLIT_PART(headline, ':', 2), ''), 'None') AS subtitle
FROM table
```

You can see it working [HERE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/4168)